# Get Imagick instance out of PHP Imagine instance

Tags: php, imagick

I have an instance of PHP Imagine:

```
$imagine = new \Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();
```

Is there a way to get the wrapped Imagick instance? I need this to remove transparency from an image. If there is no way to get the instance, how can I remove transparency from an image using PHP Imagine?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The documentation of Imagine is so poor, it's ridiculous...
I had to go into the source code of Imagine to find what I needed:

```
$imagine = new \Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();        
$image = $imagine->open($this->getFile()->getRealPath());  
$imagick = $image->getImagick();
```

Is it save to use the imagick instance?

Comment: Because Imagine makes some things easier. Do you know how to remove transparency? This sets transparency to black, but I need white:
    $imagick->setImageBackgroundColor(new \ImagickPixel("white"));
    $imagick = $imagick->flattenImages();

Comment: Hi, I found the problem. The problem was that $imagick->flattenImages() returns a new imagick instance. But imagine still works on the old one.

I solved it. See the code in my other answer.

Comment: Do you know a better solution than in my second answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
$imagine = new \Imagine\Imagick\Imagine();        
$image = $imagine->open($source);  
$imagick = $image->getImagick();
if($imagick->getImageAlphaChannel()) { #only if it has transparency            
    $imagick->setImageBackgroundColor("white");
    $imagick = $imagick->flattenImages(); 
    $imagick->writeImage();  
    $image = $imagine->open($source);                 
} 
$image->strip(); //remove GPS, EXIF, comments, ....        
$image->interlace(\Imagine\Image\ImageInterface::INTERLACE_LINE);
$image->save($dest);
```

This is not the optimal solution, I think. I would need a way to replace the imagick instance of Imagine, but there is no such method. So I am using a workaround:

```
$imagick->writeImage();  
$image = $imagine->open($source);
```

After removing transparency, I override the original file. Then I reopen the same file with imagine, which means that Imagine is then using the right image (the one without transparency)

I tested it and it works. But I think it is not really the best solution.

How can I remove transparency in Imagick without getting a new imagick instance? This would do the trick, I think.